# Invoking async function without await in Dart, like starting a thread

Tags: dart, async-await

I have two functions

```
callee() async {
  // do something that takes some time
} 

caller () async {
  await callee();
}
```

In this scenario, `caller()` waits till `callee()` finishes. I don't want that. I want `caller()` to complete right after invoking `callee()`. `callee()` can complete whenever in the future, I don't care. I just want to start it just like a thread and then forget about it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When you call the `callee` function, it returns a `Future`. The `await` then waits for that future to complete. If you don't await the future, it will eventually complete anyway, but your `caller` function won't be blocked on waiting for that. So, you can just do:

```dart
caller() {
  callee();  // Ignore returned Future (at your own peril).
}
```

If you do that, you should be aware of what happens if `callee` fails with an error. That would make the returned future complete with that error, and if you don't listen on the future, that error is considered "uncaught". Uncaught errors are handled by the current `Zone` and the default behavior is to act like a top-level uncaught error which may kill your isolate.

So, remember to handle the error.

If `callee` can't fail, great, you're done (unless it fails anyway, then you'll have fun debugging that).

Actually, because of the risk of just forgetting to await a future, the highly reocmmended [`unawaited_futures` lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unawaited_futures.html) requires that you don't *just* ignore a returned future, and instead wants you to do `unawaited(callee());` to signal that it's deliberate. (The `unawaited` function can be imported from `package:meta` and will be available from the `dart:async` library in SDK version 2.14).
The `unawaited` function doesn't handle errors though, so if you can have errors, you should do something more.

You can handle the error locally:

```dart
caller() { 
  callee().catchError((e, s) { 
    logErrorSomehow(e, s); 
  }); 
}
```

(Since null safety, this code only works if the `callee()` future has a nullable value type. From Dart 2.14, you'll be able to use `callee().ignore()` instead, until then you can do `callee().then((_) => null, onError: (e, s) => logErrorSomehow(e, s));` instead.)

or you can install an error handling zone and run your code in that:

```dart
runZoned(() {
  myProgram();
}, onError: logErrorSomehow);
```

See the [runZoned](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.16.1/dart-async/runZoned.html) function and it's `onError` parameter.

Answer (score 11):

Sure, just omit `await`. This way `callee()` is called immediately and when an async operation is called the call will be scheduled in the event queue for later execution and `caller()` is continued immediately afterwards.

This isn't like a thread though. As mentioned processing is enqueued to the event queue which means it won't be executed until the current task and all previously enqueued tasks are completed.

If you want real parallel execution you need to utilize isolates.

See also

- https://www.dartlang.org/articles/event-loop/
- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.16.1/dart-isolate/dart-isolate-library.html
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/isolate