# Is this a proper way to use async function?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use three functions at the same time asynchronously. I'm not sure that this is how I want it.

The only purpose of using inputPaymentData is that I want to use three different functions simultaneously, so I can get the result as fast as I can. I thought it would take more time if I don't use async and just use it synchronously way. Also, do I need to use await? I don't think I need to wait to get any data. Thanks.

```
void inputPaymentData(
      {required String user,
      required bool type,
      required String merchantUid,
      required String lessonUid,
      required num amount,
      required bool agree,
      required String lesson,
      required bool lessonCard,
      required String? review,
      required String coach}) async {
    inputRecordData(
        user: user,
        type: type,
        merchantUid: merchantUid,
        lessonUid: lessonUid,
        amount: amount);
    inputReservationData(
        user: user,
        agree: agree,
        lesson: lesson,
        lessonCard: lessonCard,
        review: review,
        coach: coach);
    increaseLessonNum(user);
  }

  void inputRecordData(
          {required String user,
          required bool type,
          required String merchantUid,
          required String lessonUid,
          required num amount}) =>
      paymentUseCase.inputRecordData(
          user: user,
          type: type,
          merchantUid: merchantUid,
          lessonUid: lessonUid,
          amount: amount);

  void inputReservationData(
          {required String user,
          required bool agree,
          required String lesson,
          required bool lessonCard,
          required String? review,
          required String coach}) =>
      paymentUseCase.inputReservationData(
          user: user,
          agree: agree,
          lesson: lesson,
          lessonCard: lessonCard,
          review: review,
          coach: coach);

  void increaseLessonNum(String user) =>
      paymentUseCase.increaseLessonNum(user);
```

Comment: Refer this for better understanding: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Answer (score 1):

I am using the format below for using async functions in the flutter
[P.S I am a beginner in flutter too]

```
Future<return_type> functionName() async {
  ...
  await callAPI(); //task that would take some time for execution like API calls  
  ...
  return <something of return_type>;
};
```

Comment: Good Try ! Keep it up !!

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer to your question. It isn't recommended to do like you did.

It is recommended to handle potential errors that might occur with your Future-calls. If you don't handle the failed Futures, they are uncaught and might crash your app.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551843/invoking-async-function-without-await-in-dart-like-starting-a-thread) has an excellent answer on the reason for why you shouldn't blindly do it like you've written, i.e. just fire away asynchronous methods.

**Side note:**

Your questions is ambigous. Or I misinterpreted you.. You say: *"...so I can get the result as fast as I can."* and at the same time you say: *"I don't think I need to wait to get any data."*

Those two statements contradict each other... Choose one, or clarify what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Use the format below for async functions in flutter

```
getApiData() async {

  response = await HttpServices.getCustomer();
  
}
```